# Reference to static assets with vue + webpack in electron app

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-2, webpack-file-loader

I am new to vuejs + webpack + electron and I am starting a new project with these tools.

I have hard time retrieving the path to my asset in my  tag.

My project structure is the following:

```
/my-project
  /app
    /components
      componentA.vue
      ...
    App.vue
    main.js
  /dist
  /assets
    logo.png
  package.json
  webpack.config.js
  ...
```

My webpack.config.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  // This is the "main" file which should include all other modules
  entry: './app/main.js',
  // Where should the compiled file go?
  output: {
    // To the `dist` folder
    path: './dist',
    // With the filename `build.js` so it's dist/build.js
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpeg|png|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
    }
  }
}
```

In the file componentA.vue I am trying to do the following:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img class="ui small image" src="../../assets/logo.png">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
   ...
</script>
```

But I have the following error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///logo.png
```

The browser tried to load file:///logo.png (which is wrong because it's not the full path of my asset, it misses the whole path to my-project directory) so I tried to put my asset in the output /dist folder with no result (but I am not sure I did it correctly).

Can you help me in resolving this issue ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for Webpack to return the correct path you need to make the following change:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img class="ui small image" :src="imageSource">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                imageSource: require('../../assets/logo.png')
            }
        }
</script>
```

Reference: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/126

Comment: There has to be an easier way, no? for example, if i have a static site that has 25 images that would mean 25 variables and require statements.

Comment: @StephenTetreault Yes, this can be done right in the template `:src="require('@/assets/logo.png')"`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to store images in `static` directory. With that, you can add the image path directly inside the html directive.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img src="/static/example.png">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```